# How to convert my angular 1.x App to Angular 2 App

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm having an angular app built on angular 1.4 I want to update the app to angular 2 What are the steps that should I follow to do this.

Without breaking my existing functionality. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be really big, so I will just redirect you to proper ressources:

- [UPGRADING FROM 1.X](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)
- [Preparing for and Migrating Applications to Angular 2](https://www.pluralsight.com/search?q=angular+2&clm_id=5816fddf9a25430e0003a056&CLM_Id__c=5816fddf9a25430e0003a056&categories=all)
- [Seamless Ways to Upgrade Angular 1.x to Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/seamless-ways-to-upgrade-angular-1-x-to-angular-2)
- [Migrating from Angular 1.x to Angular 2: Upgrade Strategies](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/migrating-from-angular-1-to-angular-2)

Of course, this list is not exhaustive, but I would highly advise you to make your own research and check the link I gave you (especially the first two links) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a task to be taken lightly. You will find Angular 2 very different to Angular 1.x so you will need to spend time learning the new framework before you jump in.

That said, there are libraries to help this transition.

I would start here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a big task to change from angular to angular 2 framework. as there are many diffrence between them [Please click here for more information](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)